# any way to be notified of a table or index status change in dynamodb?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to use the UpdateTable API of the AWS SDK for Java to add a couple of global secondary indexes to an existing table. I've gone through the docs, so I have each CreateGlobalSecondaryIndexAction wrapped into a GlobalSecondaryIndexUpdate, which then goes into an UpdateTableRequest.

The problem I've run into is that these table updates take awhile to process. Once one of them starts, the table is put into a status of UPDATING, and the table cannot be updated again until its status is ACTIVE. The docs say that they are asynchronous requests, and there is an AmazonDynamoDBAsyncClient that you can use to do the updates, and even gives you methods with AsyncHandlers you can pass in to respond to the events. But the problem is, these asyncHandlers get notified when the UpdateTableResult is ready. However, this does NOT mean that the table is ACTIVE and ready for another update. So you have to do polling on the table to check when its status is back to ACTIVE.

On top of this, if you are updating secondary indexes, they also get put into a status of UPDATING. So the table can be in an ACTIVE status, but if it has a secondary index with a status of UPDATING, you cannot update any other index on that table either. So you end up having to poll both the table status and the statuses of the indexes on the table to make sure they are all ACTIVE before doing another update.

Is there any event mechanism to be notified of status updates to a table and/or index to avoid this polling?

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is no push model for getting updates to a table for index updates. There is support for listening to item updates using [DynamoDB Streams](http://dynamodb-preview.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/docs/streams-dg/About.html), but nothing for table updates.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any event mechanism in place yet. If you create an index via the console you can get an email notification but that probably won't help much with what you are looking for.

Thanks for your feedback though, I'll make sure the team is aware of the interest in this feature. Feel free to reach out on our [forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=131) as well if there are other features you'd like to see!

Comment: 5 years later, and its still the same. Combined with the inability to make changes to an index (i.e. you need to remove and add another), and the inability to add and remove indexes at the same time as well as add multiple indexes, it's an huge problem that there is no way to get an event notification. Maintenance updates COULD have been easy, but no, every single decision made on DDB index changes has made it a PITA.